# Как передать изображение OpenCV в Tesseract в python?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Начал изучать tesseract, но пока не могу реализовать прямую передачу img от OpenCV в Tessseract. Как можно это сделать?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract
import numpy
import time
import cv2

def processed_img(image):
    original_image = image
    
    # threshold
    processed_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    processed_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(processed_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

    return processed_img

last_time = time.time()
while True:
    screen = numpy.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (175, 150, 525, 800)))
    print(f'{time.time() - last_time} s')
        
    last_time = time.time()
    
    screen_name = '###'
    new_screen = processed_img(screen)
    
    cv2.imshow(screen_name, new_screen)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(screen_name, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Ваш код вроде рабочий, с чем у вас проблемы?

Comment: не интегрирован pytesseract, передача изображения в реальном времени

Comment: Ну так интегрируйте и если возникнет ошибка то попросите помощи.